# Taking a sample of a CSV?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv, random

I have a program converting a CSV to a valid JSON file.

I would like to change it to take a random subset of my CSV file (as its 50k lines) and make a JSON from this. Here is my code so far -

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\CSV_1.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\Testing\\file.json', 'w')

with open('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\CSV_1.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    rows = list(reader)

with open('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\Testing\\file.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(rows, f)
```

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `random.sample(lst, n)` to the list of rows to fetch `n` number of rows from the `list of rows` randomly, something like this :

```
import random
rows_subset = random.sample(rows, 50)

# Then later in the code, dump the json and write it to the other file.
with open('gen.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(rows_subset))
```

This will give you list of `50` rows which you can then use or write to another file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a sample having a determinated number of lines, as proposed by Satish Garg, the build in tool for that is `random.sample`.
The problem is that a file object is indeed iterable, but is not a sequence: no `len` method, no direct indexing.

If you have enough memory and if the csv file can easily fit in, the simpler way is to load everything in a list with `reader.readlines()` and then take a subset with `random.sample`. Alternatively, you could read the file once to get its length, choose the line numbers to compose the sample with:

```
line_numbers_to_keep = sorted(random.sample(range(file_length), size_of_sample))
```

You can then build the sample with:

```
sample = []
index = 0
for i, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
    if i >= line_numbers_to_keep[index]:
        sample.append(row)
        index += 1
```

If you want a sample of a determinated fraction of the original file, say 1/n, a simple trick would be to skip a random number in the range [0;2*n-1)

```
next = random.randrange(2*n-1)
sample = []
for i, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
    if i >= next:
        sample.append(row)
        next = i + random.randrange(2*n-1)
```

You will not get the exact fraction, but statistically it should not be far and with an acceptable randomisation.